# Building frameworks for iOS 8 and above in XCode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have recently updated to Xcode 8. Previously I was using Xcode 7 with Swift 2.2.

I have a framework that I built in with deployment target iOS 9.3. Now that I have moved to Xcode 8 I cannot use this framework.

- Is there a way I can build a framework that will work for iOS sdks 8 and above?
- I want to set the minimum deployment target of my app to iOS 8+.

Also

- Alamofire for Swift 3 has been updated and I have updated my pod file.
- Will I be able to run the app in iOS versions above 8?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible to build frameworks with Xcode 8. Please give use more infos about your build process? How to you build your framework? Aggregated target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to build frameworks for iOS 8 with Xcode 8. But if you try to support iOS 8 you could also use Swift 3, put If you use other frameworks like Alamofire, you have to be careful, because the latest version of Alamofire (4.x) requires a minimum iOS target version of iOS 9. So you have to use Alamofire (3.x). With Alamofire 3.5 you have to use Swift 2.3

So first you have to decide what's more important for you:

- iOS 8 support: So you have to switch to Swift 2.3 and Alamofire 3.x
- Swift 3 support: So you have to drop iOS 8 support, because Alamofire 4.x requires iOS 9

Comment: Can't I have support for both? Is it posssible that I have Alamofire pods for iOS 8 and iOS 9 +

Comment: Yes, but you have to create 2 different .framework files. One for iOS9+ with Swift 3 and a legacy one for iOS 8 with Swift 2.3

Comment: Could you provide me some information or links on how it can be done

Answer (score 0):

As you know that Xcode 8 supports only `Swift 2.2` and `Swift 3`. Your framework is built on top of `Swift 2.2`. So there is no way that you can run or build the project in `Xcode 8`, you will get an error like "The project has an older version of `Swift`, Please build it with newer version of `Xcode`".

You can use Xcode 8 and you can set minimum deployment target to iOS 8. But you can't use any of the new Swift 3 features in there, I mean you can use it but it will not execute in iOS 8. For that you have to write code with class or API `availability checking` for each snippet you write.

If you use new version of `Alamofire` there is no chance that you can use it in `iOS 8.0`. You need an older version of it. Because `Alamofire` new version is `Swift 3` and have minimum deployment target of `iOS 10` I think.

So it is better to convert your project into `Swift 3` or to `Swift 2.3`. That is the best way to solve this situation. Otherwise you will see more lot of problems eventually.